# Creating Nested Folder with Batch File using two Lists for Names

Tags: arrays, batch-file, directory

I would like to create a folder structure like so:

```
Name1
|
+---SubName1
|
+---Subname2
|
\---Subname3
```

```
Name2
|
+---Subname1
|
+---Subname2
|
\---Subname3
```

I would like to have two lists for this. One with `Name1.2.3` etc. names and the second list with `SubName1.2.3` etc. names.

Could you help me with this?

```
@ECHO ON
Set list1= "Test1" "Test2" "Test3"
Set list2= "SubTest1" "SubTest2" "SubTest3"
for %%A in (%list1%) do (
    for %%B in (%list2%) do (
        md  "%%~A\%%~B"
    ))
Exit
```

Solved.

Comment: Your 'Directories' are not being 'Made' because your code is wrong. You have created two variables `%list1 %` and `%list2 %`. The correct syntx for defining variables is `Set "VariableName=ValueString"`, so yours should look more like this: `Set "list1="Name1" "Name2" "Name3""`, and `Set "list2="SubName1" "SubName2" "SubName3""`.

Comment: After you make the changes that Compo pointed out, all you need to do is nest another `FOR` command within the existing `FOR` command and then do `md "%%~A\%%~B"`

Comment: Your code works fine. What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO ON
Set list1= "Test1" "Test2" "Test3"
Set list2= "SubTest1" "SubTest2" "SubTest3"
for %%A in (%list1%) do (
    for %%B in (%list2%) do (
        md  "%%~A\%%~B"
    )
)
Exit
```

Comment: This code needs to be formatted, and should include at least a little explanatory text.